# How to use Individual User Accounts in Azure

Tags: android, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a messaging application for Android and I am using an Azure Web API as my backend which connects to an Azure SQL DB. I am trying to get the service to allow users to log in and proceed through the application with an identity. I want to use **Individual User Accounts** to do this but I do not know how.

I have been through every piece of documentation on the internet and yet I am still at a loss on how to receive a token from the service and use it to access auhtorised resources.

If someone could please highlight the appropriate methods I need to call from the generated classes as well as methods I should write myself, that would be very helpful!

This is the Account Controller that was generated:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using AcademicAssistant.Models;
using AcademicAssistant.Providers;
using AcademicAssistant.Results;

namespace AcademicAssistant.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }

    // GET api/Account/UserInfo
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("UserInfo")]
    public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
    {
        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        return new UserInfoViewModel
        {
            Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
            LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
        };
    }

    // POST api/Account/Logout
    [Route("Logout")]
    public IHttpActionResult Logout()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ManageInfo?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
    [Route("ManageInfo")]
    public async Task<ManageInfoViewModel> GetManageInfo(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IdentityUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (user == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        List<UserLoginInfoViewModel> logins = new List<UserLoginInfoViewModel>();

        foreach (IdentityUserLogin linkedAccount in user.Logins)
        {
            logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
            {
                LoginProvider = linkedAccount.LoginProvider,
                ProviderKey = linkedAccount.ProviderKey
            });
        }

        if (user.PasswordHash != null)
        {
            logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
            {
                LoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
                ProviderKey = user.UserName,
            });
        }

        return new ManageInfoViewModel
        {
            LocalLoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
            Email = user.UserName,
            Logins = logins,
            ExternalLoginProviders = GetExternalLogins(returnUrl, generateState)
        };
    }

    // POST api/Account/ChangePassword
    [Route("ChangePassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
            model.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/SetPassword
    [Route("SetPassword")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/AddExternalLogin
    [Route("AddExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddExternalLogin(AddExternalLoginBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        AuthenticationTicket ticket = AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.ExternalAccessToken);

        if (ticket == null || ticket.Identity == null || (ticket.Properties != null
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue
            && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow))
        {
            return BadRequest("External login failure.");
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalData = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(ticket.Identity);

        if (externalData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("The external login is already associated with an account.");
        }

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            new UserLoginInfo(externalData.LoginProvider, externalData.ProviderKey));

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/RemoveLogin
    [Route("RemoveLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RemoveLogin(RemoveLoginBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityResult result;

        if (model.LoginProvider == LocalLoginProvider)
        {
            result = await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        else
        {
            result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                new UserLoginInfo(model.LoginProvider, model.ProviderKey));
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
        }

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        if (externalLogin == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey));

        bool hasRegistered = user != null;

        if (hasRegistered)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

             ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            Authentication.SignIn(identity);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogins")]
    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginViewModel> GetExternalLogins(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> descriptions = Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
        List<ExternalLoginViewModel> logins = new List<ExternalLoginViewModel>();

        string state;

        if (generateState)
        {
            const int strengthInBits = 256;
            state = RandomOAuthStateGenerator.Generate(strengthInBits);
        }
        else
        {
            state = null;
        }

        foreach (AuthenticationDescription description in descriptions)
        {
            ExternalLoginViewModel login = new ExternalLoginViewModel
            {
                Name = description.Caption,
                Url = Url.Route("ExternalLogin", new
                {
                    provider = description.AuthenticationType,
                    response_type = "token",
                    client_id = Startup.PublicClientId,
                    redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, returnUrl).AbsoluteUri,
                    state = state
                }),
                State = state
            };
            logins.Add(login);
        }

        return logins;
    }

    // POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    // POST api/Account/RegisterExternal
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("RegisterExternal")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var info = await Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result); 
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Helpers

    private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private class ExternalLoginData
    {
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public IList<Claim> GetClaims()
        {
            IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ProviderKey, null, LoginProvider));

            if (UserName != null)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName, null, LoginProvider));
            }

            return claims;
        }

        public static ExternalLoginData FromIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            Claim providerKeyClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (providerKeyClaim == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Issuer)
                || String.IsNullOrEmpty(providerKeyClaim.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (providerKeyClaim.Issuer == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new ExternalLoginData
            {
                LoginProvider = providerKeyClaim.Issuer,
                ProviderKey = providerKeyClaim.Value,
                UserName = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
            };
        }
    }

    private static class RandomOAuthStateGenerator
    {
        private static RandomNumberGenerator _random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        public static string Generate(int strengthInBits)
        {
            const int bitsPerByte = 8;

            if (strengthInBits % bitsPerByte != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("strengthInBits must be evenly divisible by 8.", "strengthInBits");
            }

            int strengthInBytes = strengthInBits / bitsPerByte;

            byte[] data = new byte[strengthInBytes];
            _random.GetBytes(data);
            return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(data);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

This is the message controller I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using AcademicAssistant.Models;

namespace AcademicAssistant.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    private AcademicAssistantContext db = new AcademicAssistantContext();

    // GET: api/Messages
    [Authorize]
    public IQueryable<Message> GetMessages()
    {
        return db.Messages;
    }

    // GET: api/Messages/5
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Message))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMessage(int id)
    {
        Message message = await db.Messages.FindAsync(id);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(message);
    }

    // PUT: api/Messages/5
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutMessage(int id, Message message)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != message.MessageID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!MessageExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Messages
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Message))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMessage(Message message)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Messages.Add(message);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = message.MessageID }, message);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Messages/5
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Message))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteMessage(int id)
    {
        Message message = await db.Messages.FindAsync(id);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Messages.Remove(message);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(message);
    }

    [Authorize]
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    [Authorize]
    private bool MessageExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Messages.Count(e => e.MessageID == id) > 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You problem is an issue about general ASP.NET rather than Azure. (1) Did you successfully register user with `AccountController`? (2) Did you receive Token from your AccountController? (3) Did you confirm `MessagesController` accessible with that token?

Comment: If you hardly know how to get Token or how to get into `[Authorize]`-ed methods, [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) helps you to understand how Authentication works in ASP.NET WebApi. see `Authorization: Bearer blabla-token-strings...` should be added in request Header as ASP.NET can identify unique user with it.

Comment: @Youngjae I have registered the user account with the `AccountController  `and have received a token but I do not think I have made the `MessageController` acccessible with that token as you say. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: // Did you confirm that `Authorization` header are placed correctly in Request for `MessageController` (checked by fiddler)? what was the response?